# Trying to change the style color of a calendar date when the user clicks on it. The "Style" property changes but won't update the html

Tags: asp.net-core, events, blazor

I have a calendar that when the user clicks on the date I would like to change the style on the div to show the user that the date has been selected. I am iterating through a list of a CalendarModel and updating the actual style in the list but for some reason my html is not updating and it keeps the default styling.

Here is my code for he page:

```
@inject IBookingRepository bookingRepository
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@inject TimerService timerService

<div class="calendar-days grid-7">

    <CalendarDisabledDays calendarMonth="calendarMonth" offsetDays="offsetDays" />

    @for (int i = 0; i < calendarModel.Count; i++)
    {
        var index = i;
        <div class="@calendarModel[index].Style">
            <button @onclick="() => CalendarHasChanged(index)">@calendarModel[index].Date.Day</button>
        </div>
    }

</div>

<div class="calendar-submit grid-1">
    <EditForm OnSubmit="CreateDates" EditContext="editContext">
        <div>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-main" @onclick="ClearDates">Clear Dates<i class="fa-solid fa-eraser btn-icon"></i></button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-main">Book Dates<i class="fa-regular fa-calendar-check btn-icon"></i></button>
        </div>

        <div>
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <ValidationSummary />
        </div>
    </EditForm>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int daysInMonth { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public bool status { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public DateOnly calendarMonth { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public int offsetDays { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public BookingDatesVM? booking { get; set; }

    private DateTime date;
    private int startDay;
    private bool valid;
    private EditContext? editContext;
    private ValidationMessageStore? validationMessages;
    private List<CalendarModel>? calendarModel;

    public EventCallback<List<CalendarModel>> calendarChanged { get; set; }

    public async Task CalendarHasChanged(int index)
    {
        calendarModel[index].Style = "color:red;";

        await calendarChanged.InvokeAsync(calendarModel);
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        editContext = new(booking);
        validationMessages = new(editContext);
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        SetStartDate();
        PopulateCalendar();
        return base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the start day of the month. Used primarily if the selected month is the current month we are in.
    /// </summary>
    private void SetStartDate()
    {
        startDay = 1;
        if ((calendarMonth.Month == DateTime.Now.Month) && (calendarMonth.Year == DateTime.Now.Year))
        {
            startDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Day;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the date the user selects to the model before saving to the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="date">The selected date.</param>
    private void SetDate(DateOnly date)
    {
        if (status)
        {
            booking.CheckInDate = date;
        }
        else
        {
            booking.CheckOutDate = date;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the date in the model and sets them to the default MinValue.
    /// </summary>
    private void ClearDates()
    {
        booking.CheckInDate = DateOnly.MinValue;
        booking.CheckOutDate = DateOnly.MinValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves the selected dates to the database along with the sessionId.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task CreateDates()
    {
        valid = ValidateForm();
        if (valid)
        {
            await bookingRepository.CreateAsync(BookingMapper.FromDatesVM(booking));
            timerService.ShowTimer();
            navigationManager.NavigateTo("/bookings/info");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Manual validation of the calendar control used to check whether the dates selected are valid before storing them in the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True is the dates are allowed and false if the dates have some conflict with them.</returns>
    private bool ValidateForm()
    {
        valid = editContext.Validate();
        validationMessages?.Clear();

        var checkOutDate = editContext.Field(nameof(booking.CheckOutDate));
        var checkInDate = editContext.Field(nameof(booking.CheckInDate));

        if (booking.CheckInDate == DateOnly.MinValue)
        {
            validationMessages.Add(checkInDate, "Check in date is required.");
            valid = false;
        }
        if (booking.CheckOutDate == DateOnly.MinValue)
        {
            validationMessages.Add(checkOutDate, "Check out date is required.");
            valid = false;
        }

        return editContext.Validate();
    }

    private void PopulateCalendar()
    {
        calendarModel = new();

        for (int i = startDay; i <= daysInMonth; i++)
        {
            CalendarModel model = new();
            date = new DateTime(calendarMonth.Year, calendarMonth.Month, i);
            model.Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(date);
            model.isAvailable = true;

            calendarModel.Add(model);
        }
    }

    public class CalendarModel()
    {
        public string Style { get; set; } = "active";
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
        public bool isAvailable { get; set; } = true;
    }
}
```

Im not sure what is wrong here but the code inside the CalendarHasChanged method is being executed because when I debug it the list item that was clicked on is changed to the "color:red;" string I have set in the method but the html remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you click the button,you would modify the class attribute of the div, instead of append    style attribute to  your button

```
<div class="@calendarModel[index].Style">
    <button @onclick="() => CalendarHasChanged(index)">@calendarModel[index].Date.Day</button>
</div>
```

....

```
public async Task CalendarHasChanged(int index)
    {
        calendarModel[index].Style = "color:red;";

        await calendarChanged.InvokeAsync(calendarModel);
    }
```

You have to add a css file name of `calendar.razor.css`(css isolate) to your page folder

```
div .targetclass > button {
    // you could modify the color based on your requirement
    color: red;
    background-color: aqua
}
```

....

```
public async Task CalendarHasChanged(int index)
{
    calendarModel[index].Style = "targetclass";

    await calendarChanged.InvokeAsync(calendarModel);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: of course that was a huge oversight on my end. Quick question why dobwe have to create the isolation file in the css? Why does this not work with the regular css files?

Comment: It would also work with regular css file,but css isolation would simplify CSS and avoid collisions with other components or libraries